# SAP UI5: object expected error in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, sapui5

i am using SAP UI5 and don't know why is it showing `object expected` in line 347 while running index.html file in ie.

```
 <html>
       <head>
              <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

              <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                      type="text/javascript"
                      id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                      data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.ux3"
                      data-sap-ui-theme="sap_goldreflection" >
              </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="OPM_CM.js"></script>
              <script>
                     sap.ui.localResources("opm");
                     var view = sap.ui.view({id:"OPM_CM1", viewName:"opm.OPM_CM", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
                     //view.placeAt("content");

                     buildShell();
              </script>

       </head>
       <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
              <div id="content"></div>
       </body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be reproducible anymore. I'm voting to close this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because the sap object is not available.

```
<script>
     function init(){
            sap.ui.localResources("opm");
                 var view = sap.ui.view({id:"OPM_CM1", viewName:"opm.OPM_CM", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
                 //view.placeAt("content");

                 buildShell();
     }
     window.addEventListener('load',init);
          </script>
```

adding your code to a function and calling it on body onload may do the trick.
Note: please also give more details about the error you are getting.